# Golang on macOS - how to pass arguments to .app executable

Tags: go

I'm building an app to display files paths on macOS in a window, it's working correctly when I compile it and run it from the CLI:

```
❯ go build main.go
❯ ./main "test1" "test2"
```

The app opens the window and correctly shows the paths of the files.

However, after running `make` and turning it into an .app executable, I obviously can't pass CLI arguments anymore.

If I try to drag and drop a picture, or any type of file over the app, nothing happens, and if I select a file and do right-clic + open with... {my app}, I get an error:

```
The document “not_default.gif” could not be opened. helloworld cannot open files in the “GIF image” format.
```

Do you have any idea of a library, documentation or code I can use to pass file paths to the .app executable, or what's causing the error when I try to open the files with my .app ?

Comment: How are you converting it to `.app`? What does the make command do?

Comment: makefile:
.PHONY: all

all: clean build run

.PHONY: clean

clean:
 @ rm -rf ./helloworld.app ./ui/build
 @ echo "[✔️] Clean complete!"

.PHONY: build

build:
 @ cd ./ui && npm install
 @ cd ./ui && npm run build
 @ mkdir -p ./helloworld.app/Contents/MacOS
 @ go build -o ./helloworld.app/Contents/MacOS/helloworld
 @ echo "[✔️] Build complete!"

.PHONY: run

run:
 @ open ./helloworld.app
 @ echo "[✔️] App is running!"

Comment: Check the `open` man page for how to pass arguments. This isn’t related to Go.